# Program not giving output

Tags: python, hex, output

I need some assistance I am trying to break and IP header down in Python and I have my code written, but I am not getting anything back on the screen. I do not know what I am missing. Suggestions are welcome:

```
import struct 
from collections import OrderedDict

def tcpheader (rawTCP):
    #Using dict for the dictionary
    tcp=OrderedDict.fromkeys({})
    tcp['ttl']=struct.unpack('!H',rawTCP[8:12]) [0] # H! is to unpack the hex file and then search for the portion specified
    tcp['totalength']=struct.unpack('!H',rawTCP[0:20]) [0]
    tcp['sourceip']=struct.unpack('!H',rawTCP[12:16]) [0]
    tcp['destip']=struct.unpack('!H',rawTCP[16:20]) [0]
    return tcp #this is the proper way to break the loop and return 

def tcpdecode():
    infile=open ('C:/users/jwattenbarger/desktop/ip.dd', 'rb') #this is opening the ip.dd file 
    rawTCP=infile.read(40)
    #IPraw=infile.read (40)
    tcp=tcpheader(rawTCP)
    #tcp=tcpheader(IPraw)
    print ("ttl:", tcp['ttl']) #these are printing the data 
    print ("totalength:", tcp['totalength'])
    print ("sourceip:", tcp['sourceip'])
    print ("destip:", tcp['destip'])
    Print ("Temp")
    for i in tcp: #associating i with tcp 
        print (i, "\t",tcp[i]) #printing tcp to the screen in a table
```

Comment: Did you *call* `tcpdecode()`?

Comment: Thanks for the help on getting the code in. No I guess I did not, where should I call it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `tcpdecode()`; just add the line:

```
tcpdecode()
```

at the bottom of your module.

Comment: So I would place it under print (i, "\t", area or under the print ("destip area?

Comment: You'd place it at the end, with **no** indentation.

Comment: Just got it when you posted sorry Python newb here. Thanks

Comment: I sure will how do you correct a struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2